# Js trim string with substring

Tags: javascript, string

I have string like this:

```
var test = 'vv<br>cfvxcv<br>&nbsp;<br>vv xcv x<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>';
```

Need remove all `&nbsp;<br>` from the end. The result must be: `vv<br>cfvxcv<br>&nbsp;<br>vv xcv x`

I tried:

```
test = test.replace(/^\&nbsp;<br>+|\&nbsp;<br>+$/g, '');
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `.replace(/((\&nbsp;)|(<br>))+$/g, '')`

Comment: Remove the start-of-line indicator `^`

Comment: a minor extension to what @freedomn-m suggested `replace(/(?:\&nbsp;|<br>)+$/g, ''`)

Answer (score 0):

```
const trimS = (str, delimiter) => {
  const pattern = `[^\\${delimiter}]`;
  // const start = str.search(pattern); // trim both sides
  const start = 0; // trim only right side of string
  const stop = str.length - str.split('').reverse().join('').search(pattern);
  return str.substring(start, stop);
};

const test = 'vv<br>cfvxcv<br>&nbsp;<br>vv xcv x<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>';
console.log(trimS(test, '&nbsp;<br>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `^` character means start of line - you don't need this.  But the `+` only applies to the character in front of it, so you need to group them to get the `+` to apply to the group, giving:

```js
var test = 'vv<br>cfvxcv<br>&nbsp;<br>vv xcv x<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>';
test = test.replace(/(\&nbsp;<br>)+$/g, '');
console.log(test, test == "vv<br>cfvxcv<br>&nbsp;<br>vv xcv x")
```

which doesn't quote work because your requirement of

> remove `&nbsp;<br>` from the end

should be

> remove all `&nbsp;` and `<br>` from the end

giving:

```js
    var test = 'vv<br>cfvxcv<br>&nbsp;<br>vv xcv x<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>';
    test = test.replace(/((\&nbsp;)|(<br>))+$/g, '');
    console.log(test, test == "vv<br>cfvxcv<br>&nbsp;<br>vv xcv x")
```

Answer (score 0):

The substring returns the string between the start and the end index of the string.

For more references: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

```
 test = test.substring(0, 34)
```

Output: `'vv<br>cfvxcv<br>&nbsp;<br>vv xcv x'`